# Is it possible to delete a queue or topic from ActiveMQ from a client application?

Tags: activemq-classic, messagebroker

We are using ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.15.15. I believe when the broker receives a new message it creates the corresponding queue or topic.

Is it possible to completely delete (not purge!) a topic or a queue? Purging does not help, assuming a queue has been created and a scheduled message has been put!

I didn't find any solution using the [client lib](https://github.com/team-supercharge/nest-amqp) I'm using right now. Probably this is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using an AMQP client but as a general rule none of the clients that speak to the broker can manage broker resources in a meaningful way.  To accomplish management tasks you would need to look at using JMX to call broker management endpoints or use the Jolokia support to operate via REST calls.

Some documentation on broker monitoring is [here](https://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq)